# AUR problems with installations

Tags: security, archlinux

i've a problem in my arch linux distribution, i've added the black arch repo to this one.
When i try to install the impacket suit or crackmapexec using
sudo pacman -S impacket
This is my output

```
Packages (12) python-click-8.1.2-1  python-flask-2.1.1-1  python-itsdangerous-2.1.2-2  python-jinja-1:3.0.3-1  python-ldap3-2.9.1-3  python-markupsafe-2.1.1-1  python-pcapy-1.0.5-1
              python-pyasn1-0.4.8-7  python-pycryptodome-3.14.1-1  python-pycryptodomex-3.12.0-1  python-werkzeug-2.1.1-1  impacket-0.9.24-1

Total Download Size:    5.49 MiB
Total Installed Size:  35.42 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 impacket-0.9.24-1-any                                                                1802.1 KiB  1502 KiB/s 00:01 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-pycryptodomex-3.12.0-1-x86_64                                                 1354.7 KiB  7.47 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-pycryptodome-3.14.1-1-x86_64                                                   980.6 KiB  6.38 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-ldap3-2.9.1-3-any                                                              442.8 KiB  3.52 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-werkzeug-2.1.1-1-any                                                           328.6 KiB  3.31 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-jinja-1:3.0.3-1-any                                                            240.5 KiB  2.45 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-click-8.1.2-1-any                                                              154.7 KiB  2.07 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-flask-2.1.1-1-any                                                              133.6 KiB  1284 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-pyasn1-0.4.8-7-any                                                             115.2 KiB  1496 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-itsdangerous-2.1.2-2-any                                                        24.9 KiB   324 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-pcapy-1.0.5-1-x86_64                                                            22.5 KiB   271 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 python-markupsafe-2.1.1-1-x86_64                                                       18.6 KiB   295 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 Total (12/12)                                                                           5.5 MiB  1803 KiB/s 00:03 [#####################################################################] 100%
(12/12) checking keys in keyring                                                                                   [#####################################################################] 100%
(12/12) checking package integrity                                                                                 [#####################################################################] 100%
(12/12) loading package files                                                                                      [#####################################################################] 100%
(12/12) checking for file conflicts                                                                                [#####################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/AES.py exists in filesystem
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/AES.pyi exists in filesystem
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/ARC2.py exists in filesystem
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/Blowfish.pyi exists in filesystem
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/_EKSBlowfish.pyi exists in filesystem
python-pycryptodomex: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/_Salsa20.abi3.so exists in filesystem
<SNIP>
python-click: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/shell_completion.py exists in filesystem
python-click: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/termui.py exists in filesystem
python-click: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/testing.py exists in filesystem
python-click: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/types.py exists in filesystem
python-click: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/utils.py exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

As aditional information after the configuration of user i've installed python and python3-pip before the other installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you already check the following thread on the arch forums?

[https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249702[1]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249702%5B1%5D)

Also this one:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#%22Failed_to_commit_transaction_(conflicting_files)%22_error [2]

my pacman installation of impacket runs apparently without issues:

```
$ sudo pacman -S impacket 
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (6) python-ldap3-2.9.1-3  python-pcapy-1.0.5-1  python-pyasn1-0.4.8-7  python-pycryptodome-3.14.1-1
             python-pycryptodomex-3.12.0-1  impacket-0.9.24-1

Total Download Size:    4.61 MiB
Total Installed Size:  30.25 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 impacket-0.9.24-1-any                   1802.1 KiB  2.42 MiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 python-pycryptodomex-3.12.0-1-x86_64    1354.7 KiB  4.35 MiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 python-pycryptodome-3.14.1-1-x86_64      980.6 KiB  5.04 MiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 python-ldap3-2.9.1-3-any                 442.8 KiB  3.70 MiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 python-pyasn1-0.4.8-7-any                115.2 KiB  1719 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 python-pcapy-1.0.5-1-x86_64               22.5 KiB   561 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 Total (6/6)                                4.6 MiB  2.53 MiB/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) checking keys in keyring                                        [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) checking package integrity                                      [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) loading package files                                           [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) checking for file conflicts                                     [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) checking available disk space                                   [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/6) installing python-pycryptodome                                  [#######################################] 100%
(2/6) installing python-pycryptodomex                                 [#######################################] 100%
(3/6) installing python-pyasn1                                        [#######################################] 100%
(4/6) installing python-pcapy                                         [#######################################] 100%
(5/6) installing python-ldap3                                         [#######################################] 100%
(6/6) installing impacket                                             [#######################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
```